# List To ListItem to create new MarkerStyle Bullet

Tags: wpf

How can i do this with code?

```
<FlowDocument Background="GhostWhite">
  <List MarkerOffset="25" MarkerStyle="UpperRoman" StartIndex="5">
    <ListItem>
      <Paragraph>Boron</Paragraph>
      <List Margin="0" Padding="0"  >
        <ListItem Margin="40,0,0,0">
          <Paragraph>Symbol: B</Paragraph>
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem Margin="40,0,0,0">
          <Paragraph>Atomic Mass: 10.811</Paragraph>
        </ListItem>
      </List>
    </ListItem>
</List>
</FlowDocument>
```

specifically:

```
<Paragraph>Boron</Paragraph>
  <List Margin="0" Padding="0"  >
```

this part.

Comment: The MSDN doc of [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.list.aspx), where you copied this XAML, also contains C# and VB sample code that shows how to compose FlowDocument content in code.

Comment: I have seen the link. but it will not show the code to do this:<Paragraph>Boron</Paragraph>
  <List Margin="0" Padding="0"  > Please Help. Can i do it with c# code?

Answer (score 1):

From the MSDN page @Clemens added a link to, [List class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.list.aspx):

```
List listx = new List();
// Set the space between the markers and list content to 25 DIP.
listx.MarkerOffset = 25;
// Use uppercase Roman numerals.
listx.MarkerStyle = TextMarkerStyle.UpperRoman;
// Start list numbering at 5.
listx.StartIndex = 5;

// Create the list items that will go into the list.
ListItem liV = new ListItem(new Paragraph(new Run("Boron")));
ListItem liVI = new ListItem(new Paragraph(new Run("Carbon")));
ListItem liVII = new ListItem(new Paragraph(new Run("Nitrogen")));
ListItem liVIII = new ListItem(new Paragraph(new Run("Oxygen")));
ListItem liIX = new ListItem(new Paragraph(new Run("Fluorine")));
ListItem liX = new ListItem(new Paragraph(new Run("Neon")));

// Finally, add the list items to the list.
listx.ListItems.Add(liV);
listx.ListItems.Add(liVI);
listx.ListItems.Add(liVII);
listx.ListItems.Add(liVIII);
listx.ListItems.Add(liIX);
listx.ListItems.Add(liX);
```

Notice where the `ListItem`s are created. Each `ListItem` is constructed with a new `Paragraph` object, which is constructed with a new `Run` object, which is in turn constructed with a text string. This is how you add text to a `Paragraph` in code. In XAML, the `Run` object is implicitly added by the WPF Framework although you also can declare them explicitly.

```
<Paragraph>
    <Run>Boron</Run>
</Paragraph>
```